# My app is rejected. It access '/usr/lib/libpcap.A.dylib' What can I do to avoid it?

Tags: cocoa, macos, wifi, appstore-approval, ssid

I submitted a simple app to the Mac OSX App Store, but it was rejected with the following explanation:

"The application is creating files in, writing to, or opening for Read/Write access the following location(s):

'/usr/lib/libpcap.A.dylib'"

I use some carbon code such as FSMountServerVolumeSync and FSGetCatalogInfo.

Is there any way I could void this?

Edit:
It is caused by a shell-script not carbon: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport -I | sed -e 's/^  *SSID: //p' -e d\")"

Comment: Standard Carbon calls shouldn't cause a problem. Are you sure you're not using `libpcap` in any way? If you're not, then you should respond to Apple and tell them exactly what your code is doing and that you can't possibly be writing to `libpcap.A.dylib`.

Comment: I'm sure nothing is writing there because use need root access for that. These calls could be non-standard APIs. No Idea, I guess I just have to write to Apple than

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the problem is due to using the `airport` command-line utility, if you’re targeting Mac OS X v10.6+ I suggest you use the [CoreWLAN framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Networking/Reference/CoreWLANFrameworkRef/) to obtain the SSID of the current wireless interface:

```
#import <CoreWLAN/CoreWLAN.h>

CWInterface *wif = [CWInterface interface];
if (wif) {
    // There's an active WiFi connection; get its SSID
    NSString *currentSSID = wif.ssid;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bavarious! This is super simple. I googled it for hours but this never showed up. That's why I ended up with that dodgy shell script. It works like a charm! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured out what's causing the problem. 
I can use **fs_usage terminal command** to see what's happening in the filesysytem. I use "**sudo fs_usage -w | grep "/usr/lib**"

This is the problem:

15:58:03.049  stat64                                 /usr/lib/libpcap.A.dylib                                                                0.000007   airport
15:58:03.049  open              F=4        (R_*_*_)  /usr/lib/libpcap.A.dylib                                                                0.000020   airport

I use an shell script to get the name of the active WIFI connection. It is obvious that airport opens /usr/lib/libpcap.A.dylib for reading, other libraries are not opened like that (no (R_*_*) )

EDIT: This was the answer to my second question, but Bavarious simple solution to get the SSID eliminates all the hassles for me ;)